# out keyword is used only for Value types variables ? Cant it be used against reference Variables like Class Objects

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
int i =5;
classA _classAObj;
void print(out i)
{
    i=10;
    Console.Write(i);
}
```

---

```
void printMethod(out _classAObj)
{
    _classAObj = new ClassB();
    Console.Write(typeof(_classAObj ).ToString());
}
```

I Need more clarity over the referenceType behaviour change in this

```
printmethod()
```

Comment: simple answer - try it and find out :)

Comment: `out` works for both, value and reference types. What _exactly_ do you want to know? What are you trying to do? Note that the code you posted isn't valid c#.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that it can be used only for value types? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) doesn't mention it and this compiles just fine:

```
public void Foo(out string test)
{
    test = "";
}
```

`out` and `ref` are similar, but `out` requires to initialize the variable in the method whereas `ref` requires it to be initialized before it is passed to the method. Both can be reference types.

This article from J.Skeet is worth reading and explains it all: [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)